# Can the result of this HQL be reused?

Tags: hive, hql

As known, HQL is not SQL and will be executed using JAVA, so I have 2 view regarding the following HQL and could anyone tell me which one is correct?

1. The content inside the `c` will be executed initially and then its result will be stored somewhere and consequently reused when `c` is called;
2. `c` is just the short name of the HQL inside `from` and will be executed each time when `c` is called.

HQL:

```
  from(
             select
                   b.un_connect_id,
                   b.imp_list_no
              from
                     (select  a.*,
                          row_number() over(partition by list_no order by op_day desc, imp_list_no desc, un_connect_id desc) rno
                 from sssss a
                 ) b
              where b.rno = 1
             ) c
    insert overwrite table yyyyyyyyy partition(tmp = 'TMP',channel,business)
        select c.un_connect_id,
               c.business
        insert overwrite table xxxxxx
        select c.list_no,
               c.customer_no,
               c.party_no,
               '${nominal_format_date}' as op_day
```

Comment: It's _option 1_ :  **The content inside the c will be executed initially and then its result will be stored somewhere and consequently reused when c is called;**

Comment: @mrsrinivas  Thx for your reply. Can you please give more explaination or details? Where is the result stored and when will it be released? If possible, how is this process implemented in Java?

Comment: @mrsrinivas  In addition, what's the difference between this clause and `with....as...` clause? Any help will be appreciated....